Ларавель бродкастеры дружат с cURL?
делаю ларавел-приложение с вебсокетом. использую реверб и вещатели(ShouldBroadcastNow).
вебсокет настроил через nginx
    location /app {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
}

подключаеться нормально, однако когда триггерю ивент - получаю ошибку

Invalid crypto_method request option: TLS 1.2 not supported by your version of cURL

cURL v7.29.0
предполагаю что это связано с тем , что вещатель отправляет хттп в сокет сервер(или что то типа этого), тк при использовании вещателей с ShouldBroadcast и очередью - фейлятся задания с той же ошибкой
broadcasting.php
        'reverb' => [
        'driver'         => 'reverb',
        'key'            => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
        'secret'         => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id'         => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
        'options'        => [
            'host'   => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'port'   => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
            'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
            'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
        ],
        'client_options' => [
            // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
        ],
    ],


решением оказалось определение константы CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2
if ( ! defined('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2')) {
define('CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2', 6);
}
код кинул в AppServiceProvider
